# Efficient Rate Limiting of Async Tasks (N executions per time interval)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

How do I implement an efficient rate limiting algoritm (N executions of a certain action per time interval) when using .Net 4.0/4.5 Tasks? For example, I want `SendMessageAsync` to block (without sending another message) if more than N messages where sent in a second.

```
        await Task.WhenAll(
                    Enumerable.Range(0, TOTAL_MESSAGES)
                    .Select(async x =>
                    {
                        await clientSession.SendMessageAsync(CreateMessage());
                    }));
```

I've tried using `Task.Delay` inside `SendMessageAsync` but since awaiting `Task.Delay` immediatelly returns, then the next message will be sent without any blocking.

```
public async Task<ResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(RequestMessage message)
{

    int sleepTime;
    if (throttler.ShouldThrottle(out sleepTime))
    {
        await Task.Delay(sleepTime);
    }

    return await InternalMessageWithoutWaitingAsync(message);
}
```

I could change `await Task.Delay(sleepTime)` into `Thread.Sleep(sleepTime)` thus waiting before going async but I wonder if this is a good practice when using Tasks.

Comment: I'd only start the next task when the "throttler" signals "go". I thinks that a better pattern than starting all tasks and waiting immediately with most of them.

Comment: Time-based operations like throttling *over a time interval* are best done using Rx instead of `async` directly.

Comment: @usr - or pass the task to the throttler and let it start it whenever it thinks is right. Anyway - why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @StephenCleary Since the code is part of a library, if possible, I would like not to use Rx (or any other third party).

Comment: @RobertMircea using `Thread.Sleep` is definitely a bad practice (waste of resources). I did not get your concern about `next message will be sent without any blocking`. Does this mean that you need to execute all tasks in order? If your scenario is really complicated, you can take a look on implementing your own `TaskScheduler`: [How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx)

Comment: @outcoldman As @StephenCleary mentioned, the question is about throttling over a time interval and not about limiting the number of parallel operations (concurrency) at a certain moment. `next message will be sent without any blocking` means that the next message is sent without respecting the rate limit over the 1 second interval that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @RobertMircea then you can implement your own `TaskScheduler` (if you don't want to use `Rx`)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Thread.Sleep` is not a good practice in `async` code.

You could probably get what you need like this:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(N);
public async Task<ResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(RequestMessage message)
{
  await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    return await InternalMessageWithoutWaitingAsync(message);
  }
  finally
  {
    ReleaseSemaphoreAfterDelayAsync();
  }
}

private async Task ReleaseSemaphoreAfterDelayAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(TimeInterval);
  _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: I used this snippet of code to generate 400K msgs. The problem is that many tasks get created consuming 800mb RAM while only N are actually running processing messages, the rest are blocked by semaphore. How can I stop creating new tasks while waiting for processing to finish?
```
        await Task.WhenAll(
                    Enumerable.Range(0, 400000)
                    .Select(async x =>
                    {
                            var responsePdu = await client.SendPduAsync(NewMessage());
                            [...]                        
                    }));```

Comment: When I run [this code](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/7193d2e9b66eabe559f7) in ANTS Memory Profiler, I see 400k tasks taking up 17,600,000 bytes. It's probably some local variables being lifted that is causing the memory pressure; see Stephen Toub's resources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T) for tuning ideas.

Comment: Off the top of my head: 1) Ensure `InternalMessageWithoutWaitingAsync` is a separate method, and that `SendMessageAsync` really is just the code above (i.e., remove all local vars from that method); 2) You can move the semaphore throttling higher in your code; 3) Reconsider Rx; `async` simply wasn't designed for this.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have no problem in reconsidering Rx. The only paradigm that I want to keep is the beauty of giving the caller the opportunity to use Task<ResponseMessage>. The library is designed so that: task is cancelled if no reply within 30sec comes back from server, task captures the exception in case of error communicating with the server, or the task is giving the caller the option to wait for reply from server. The producer "streams" messages towards the library (in production is not limited in any way to known in advance amounts of messages). I hope I can keep that with Rx.

Comment: Modern versions of Rx interoperate cleanly with `async`. Check out the `ToTask` operator for example.

Comment: @StephenCleary I get a compiler warning that ReleaseSemaphoreAfterDelayAsync is not awaited. Should it be awaited?

Comment: @Prabhu: You could `await` it. Note that VS2013 does not allow `await` in a `finally` (or catch), so that would complicate the code. The next version of VS is expected to allow `await` with a `finally` block.